# django rest serialize a string when model object is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

having trouble serializer a string during a try/except statement.

here i have a endpoint that calls another function `refund` the response i get back from that function i'm trying to serialize.

```js
class RefundOrder(APIView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print('test')
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body_data = json.loads(body_unicode)
        amount = body_data['amount']
        tenant = get_object_or_404(Tenant, pk=kwargs['tenant_id'])

        refund = SquareGateway(tenant).refund(amount)
        serializer = RefundSerializer(refund)
        return  Response(serializer.data)
```

this is the function that gets called in the post endpoint. i added it in a try statement to handle the errors from [square](https://squareup.com/us/en) api. if the api call fails, i want to return an error if their is one, else serialize that data.

```js
    def refund(self, order, amount, reason):

        try:
            response = self.client.transaction().create_refund(stuff)
                
            refund = Refund(
                order=order,
                amount=response.refund.amount_money.amount,
            )
            refund.save()
            return refund
        except ApiException as e:
            return json.loads(e.body)['errors'][0]['detail']
```

this is the the Refundserialize

```js
class RefundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Refund
        fields = ('id', 'amount')
```

serializing the string doesn't throw an error it just doesn't return the error message that im returning.Currently it returns a empty serialized object.

Comment: What's your question? Does your code produce an error message? If so post the traceback.

Comment: sorry about that just updated my question.

Comment: So your problem must be coming from this statement `json.loads(e.body)['errors'][0]['detail']`

Comment: yes so `json.loads(e.body)['errors'][0]['detail']` returns a string `One or more refunds might already have been applied to this payment` and when i pass that string to ` RefundSerializer(refund)` returns a an empty object like this  `{"amount": null} ` i want to return that string instead of the object. if the api call fails.

Comment: So you want to return an object that looks like `{"amount": "One or more refunds might already have been applied to this payment"}`, right?

Comment: yea but, i want the object to look like this `{"error": "One or more refunds might already have been applied to this payment"}`

Comment: Maybe you should add a try/except block in `RefundOrder.post()` to catch and `refund` raise the `ApiException` and respond with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, You need a ***custom API exception which returns a custom message***.
So, Initially create a custom exception class as below,

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework import status


class GenericAPIException(APIException):
    """
    raises API exceptions with custom messages and custom status codes
    """
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail, status_code=None):
        self.detail = detail
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
```

Then ***raise*** the exception in **`refund()`** function.

```
def refund(self, order, amount, reason):

    try:
        # your code
    except ApiException as e:
        raise GenericAPIException({"message":"my custom msg"})
```

Comment: glad to hear that!